# Как получить cookie в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie

Пробую сделать сайт на python без использования всяких фрэймворков(поспорили с друзьями). На сайте присутствует смена темы, которая реализована через cookie.

Как получить эти самые cookie для нужного юзера? То есть те, которые сохранились для данного пользователя при прошлом посещении?

Просто через `requests` возвращается пустой список вместо тех данных, которые нужны.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Без фреймворков - на голых TCP сокетах? Было бы мощно. По вопросу: *как получить эти самые cookie* **откуда**? Вы знаете, где они на Вашем сервере хранятся?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, мы несильно вдавались в подробности что, как и почему, просто я решил, а уже потом поспорили с другом. Нет, к сожалению, не знаю где хранятся куки...